# Can't access context in react project - getting 'undefined' error

Tags: reactjs, react-context

In my React project, I'm pulling context from the file  `AuthContext.js` into my `NavBar` component. Specifically, I'm trying to access the state variables `isAuthenticated` and the function `toggleAuth`.
Only problem is that when I try to load the page, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'isAuthenticated' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

   6 | const Navbar = () => {
   7 |   const { isLightTheme, light, dark } = useContext(ThemeContext);
>  8 |   const { isAuthenticated, toggleAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
   9 |   const theme = isLightTheme ? light : dark;
  10 |   return (
  11 |     <nav style={{ background: theme.ui, color: theme.syntax }}>
```

I'm confused because I'm using context in the exact same way for other contexts, and it's working fine (eg, using themes from my `ThemeContext.js` file).

Any suggestions as to why my AuthContext is failing but ThemeContext is working?

The NavBar component where I need both `ThemeContext` and `AuthContext`


`NavBar.jsx`

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { ThemeContext } from '../contexts/ThemeContext';
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/AuthContext';

const Navbar = () => {
  const { isLightTheme, light, dark } = useContext(ThemeContext);
  const { isAuthenticated, toggleAuth } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const theme = isLightTheme ? light : dark;
  return (
    <nav style={{ background: theme.ui, color: theme.syntax }}>
      <h1>Context App</h1>
      <div onClick={() => toggleAuth()}>
        { isAuthenticated ? 'Logged in' : 'Logged out' }
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
 
export default Navbar;
```

My Auth context file `AuthContext.js`:

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

class AuthContextProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false
  }
  toggleAuth = () => {
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: !this.state.isAuthenticated });
  }
  render() {  
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={{...this.state, toggleAuth: this.toggleAuth}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
 
export default AuthContextProvider;
```

Theme context file `ThemeContext.js`

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

export const ThemeContext = createContext();

class ThemeContextProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    isLightTheme: true,
    light: { syntax: '#555', ui: '#ddd', bg: '#eee' },
    dark: { syntax: '#ddd', ui: '#333', bg: '#555'}
  }
  render() { 
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={{...this.state}}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
 
export default ThemeContextProvider;
```

Comment: Did you wrap Navbar in AuthContextProvider in the root component?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not using your AuthContextProvider in your root component.
Should be something like

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import AuthContextProvider from './context/AuthContext';
import ThemeContextProvider from '../contexts/ThemeContext';

ReactDOM.render(
   <AuthContextProvider>
     <ThemeContextProvider>
       <App />
     </ThemeContextProvider>
   </AuthContextProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```